# Can Node.js pass down node_modules dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2

So I have a ec2 instance running on a free tier on amazon's web services. I'm running a Ubuntu server that has been configured to run at its public address. Here is the server.js code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

/*
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("CONTENT COMING")
})
*/

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.listen(3000, () => {console.log("Server Running on port 3000")})
```

as you can see I use express to serve a static file server just so I can develop locally and easily deploy online to the server when the time comes. Inside the ***public*** folder I have an ***index.html*** and a ***test.js*** file to serve. My question is will I have to create another instance of a node package manager to install packages to use in my program?

For example, if I want to require node.js File-System by using

```
const fs = require('fs')
```

would I have to create another `npm init` to then install my dependencies or could I somehow use my dependencies from the directory above?

Comment: Not sure I understand the context, your server is running on an EC2 instance so any new code you want to add would need redeployed (along with any new packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. You only need one.

NPM modules can be incorporated into your code several folders down in your project.

Take for example a project folder:

```
/root
   app.js
   package.json
   /public
      index.html
   /node_modules
      ...
```

All modules in the `node-module` folder can be used in any project sub-folder.

Say, you have a file named `anotherApp.js` in a folder down the line, it will 'inherit' all node modules installed in any parent folder. Therefore, it will also be able to access every module that is in the project root `node_module` folder.

```
/root
   /somefoldername
      /anotherfolder
         /application
            anotherApp.js
   /node_modules
      ...
```

I should add, that NPM (Node package manager) is there to handle locally installed modules. The `fs` (File System) modules does come with node and is installed as a global, therefore you do not need to install it via NPM. Check out https://www.npmjs.com/ for a full list of available downloadable modules.

Comment: This answers my basic question, however I'm still getting an error when trying to require a package from a javascript file inside of the public folder

Comment: Are you running said file in the browser?

Comment: I believe so. I've been researching it all morning and might have found the issue. The require package only works, per say, on the back-end. I read that some technologies like browserify, CommonJS, and webpack will work for the client side of the application. So I'm trying to use browserify but i'm still having trouble.

Comment: Exactly. You can try using requirejs which I believe should give you the power to write `require()` scripts. I would recommend finding a dist version of a module (if exists), one that is browser compatible, and place it in a `<script src="link/to/file.js">`.

Comment: okay, I'll try and see if that works. Thanks man you've been a great help!

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I would always suggest using `git` to synchronize your local files and your files on the EC2 server.

To install the same dependency on both your local and cloud, you can save it in your `package.json`
e.g. `npm install --save express`

And on your server, `npm install` would install all the dependencies listed in `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to insert the dependencies in your current project in your `package.json` and make sure that you create a deployment flow that installs it.

If you are having trouble to deploy to your EC2 Instance, I would recommend you to start one instance using Amazon EB and use CodeShip to deploy it.

Another option would be to run it using Heroku and integrating with git.

Both will take care of installing the dependencies before of running it.